# Create folder using GitHub API

Tags: git, github, github-api

Is there any way to create a new folder in git repository using [their API](http://developer.github.com/v3/)? Is it possible to do this with [Trees API](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, but you'd need to create a file in the directory because git only tracks directories with files in them.

Example:

Say we have a user called "foo" who has a repo called "bar". The repo has the following contents:

```
├── LICENSE
├── main.go
├── main_test.go
└── README.md
```

If we want to create a file in the `examples` directory called `example.go`, we would issue the following request:

```
PUT /repos/foo/bar/contents/examples/example.go
```

The template for the request to create new files is as follows:

```
PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
```

See http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you tell me if it is possible to rename git repo using API?