# How to create a new directory in a repo using PyGithub?

Tags: python, github, github-api, pygithub

Just as we can create new files in a Github repo using `PyGithub`, can we create directories/folders in a Github repo using *PyGithub*? I have been searching through the PyGithub docs but I haven't found anything substantial.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12258399/2614364

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create directory using the same method as for when creating a file. But the catch is to create a file inside directory since Git tracks only folders which have files inside [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20045627/9871463).

```
>>> repo = g.get_repo("PyGithub/PyGithub")
>>> repo.create_file("example/test.txt", "test message", "content_of_file", branch="test")
{'content': ContentFile(path="example/test.txt"), 'commit': Commit(sha="5b584cf6d32d960bb7bee8ce94f161d939aec377")}
```